# How to show ul items in my case?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to keep my list item in a div that has `20px` padding in the div. I also want to make the div responsive so it shows 3 columns or 4 columns based on the browser width.

My code:

```
<div>
   <ul class="list-inline">
      <li>items1</li>
      <li>items2</li>
      <li>items3</li>
      <li>items4</li>
      <li>items5</li>
      <li>items6</li>
      <li>items7</li>
      <li>items8</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

every item is a rectangle div that contains bunch of information.

I want to divide the item to show

```
 --------------------------
|   
|   item1  item2  item3
|
|
|
```

or

```
 -------------------
|   
|   item1   item2
|
|   item3
|
```

Based on the browser width.
I also want to keep the minimum 20px of `padding` in the div.

How do I do this in bootstrap?

Comment: See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

Comment: I know grid system but no sure how to apply to the ul, li tag.

Comment: Your question is unclear, please create a [bootply](http://bootply.com) and explain what it is that you'd like to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that most classes in BS are re-usable and can be applied to different elements, so in your specific case, just treat the `UL` and `LI` elements as `DIV` and simply work with them using the regular Bootstrap grid. Like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="row list-inline">
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items1</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items2</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items3</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items4</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items5</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items6</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items7</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items8</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items9</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items10</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items11</li>
     <li class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">items12</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[See Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/hTChZc7Ap7)

As you can see, no much more than that, not even additional CSS, Bootstrap will take care of everything with its default classes

Comment: +1 from me ... I just swapped the 3 and 4 column around ... to make it 3 cols on the smaller screen (`col-xs-4`), hope you approve ;-)